# How to find the node that holds the minimum element in a binary tree in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm trying to solve a similar problem (find the shortest list in a tree of lists) and I think that solving this problem would be a good start.

Given a data type like

```
data (Ord a, Eq a) => Tree a = Nil | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

How to find the node that holds the minimum element in the binary tree above?
Please not that this is not a binary search tree.

I'm trying to think recursively: The minimum is the minimum between the left, right subtrees and the current value. However, I'm struggling to translate this to Haskell code. One of the problems that I am facing is that I want to return the tree and not just the value.

Comment: create a [`Foldable`](http://blog.jakubarnold.cz/2014/07/30/foldable-and-traversable.html) instance and `fold` with `min`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: class constraints on datatype declarations are no longer supported in Haskell 2010, and generally not recommended. So do this instead:

```
data Tree a =   Nil
              | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

Think recursively:

```
getMinTree  :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
getMinTree = snd <=< getMinTree'

getMinTree' :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe (a, Tree a)
getMinTree' Nil = ???
getMinTree' (Node Nil value Nil) = ???
getMinTree' (Node Nil value right) = ???
getMinTree' (Node left value Nil) = ???
getMin' (Node left value right) = ???
```

Note also: there is no need for an `Eq` constraint. Since `Eq` is a superclass of `Ord`, an `Ord` constraint implies an `Eq` constraint. I don't think you're even likely to use `==` for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still confused. In fact, before reading your answer I concluded that I need to handle theses base cases, however, I don't really now how to write the code. For example, the case "getMinTree' (Node Nil value right)" implies that we just have to compare this node with right; but I'm not sure about how to implement it.

Comment: @chi Thanks. I think I fixed it, but I'll test when I get to my computer.

Comment: @user35477, the concept is to pair up the subtree with it's smallest node.

Comment: `s/it's/its/` @dfeuer

Comment: @jdlugosz, as embarrassing as that error is, there's nothing I can do to fix it now.

Comment: I thought comments could be edited, but one char was too small to be fixed by someone other than the author?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

You can start by defining, as an auxiliary function, a minimum between only two trees. `Node`s are compared according to ther value, ignoring the subtrees, and comparing `Nil` to any tree `t` makes `t` the minimum (in a sense, we think of `Nil` as the "largest" tree). Coding this can be done by cases:

```
binaryMin :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
binaryMin Nil t = t
binaryMin t Nil = t
binaryMin (Node l1 v1 r1) (Node l2 v2 r2) = ???
```

Then, the minimum subtree follows by recursion, exploiting `binaryMin`:

```
treeMin :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
treeMin Nil = Nil
treeMin (Node left value right) = ???
   where l = treeMin left
         r = treeMin right
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct understanding. I think you should be fine when you can prove the following:

- Can the tree with min be `Nil`
- The tree with min probably has the min value at the root

So instead of just comparing the values, you might need to pattern-match the subtrees to get the value of the root node.

You didn't mention what the type of the function is. So, let's suppose it looks like so:

```
findmin :: Tree a -> Tree a
```

Now, suppose you already have a function that finds min of the tree. Something like:

```
findmin Nil = Nil -- no tree - no min
findmin (Node l x r) = case (findmin ..., findmin ...) of
       -- like you said, find min of the left, and find min of the right
       -- there will be a few cases of what the min is like on the left and right
       -- so you can compare them to x
                         some case -> how to find the min in this case
                         some other case -> how to find min in that other case
```

Perhaps, you will need to know the answers to the first two questions.

It is so hard to give an answer short of giving away the actual code, since your thinking is already correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "probably has the min value at the root"? That sounds unlikely to be correct under the circumstances, since there is no information about how the elements are arranged in the tree.

Comment: @dfeuer I think that's what the OP means by "returning the tree"